# Cucumber TestNG Gradle Parallel Execution ThreadCount

Tags: java, testng, cucumber, cucumber-java, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to run my Cucumber scenarios in parallel using the TestNG. But when I run it `'parallel=true'` it executes the test cases in thread count=10 (testng default).

I want to customise the thread count to say 2 or 3. How do I do that.? I want to run this through IntelliJ as well as through the command line (terminal) Tried using the `'jvmArgs(["-Ddataproviderthreadcount=2"])'`

**CucumberTestNGRunner**

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"path/to/features"},
        glue = {"path.to.stepdep.package"},
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        tags = "@smoke",
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = true
)
public class CucumberTestNGRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (snippet) :**

```
test {
    useTestNG()
    //jvmArgs(["-Ddataproviderthreadcount=2"])
    scanForTestClasses = false
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

**Edit (Updated):**

***Note :*** I am able to pass the *data-provider-thread-count* using
the testng.xml

What I am looking is to pass the thread count using the build.gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test Suite" data-provider-thread-count="4" >
    <test name="Test" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.abc.testrunner.CucumberTestNGRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: For this - do you have a testng.xml file? that is typically where I see the number of threads set

Comment: I am able to pass the thread count using the testng.xml, what I am looking for is to set the thread count using the build.gradle